# In ROS, how could only the first subscriber receive message on a topic

Tags: ros, foxglove-studio

I'm using Foxglove Studio to send a message to my robot but I observed that, regardless from which machine I subscribe the topic, it is always only the first subscriber that can receive messages. So I wonder what are the possible ROS configurations that make messages from a topic only available for the first subscriber that registers with ROS Core? There are probably something needs to be tuned with Foxglove Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a topic can be subscribed by multiple subscribers, that's the main point of it I believe. However I found [this](http://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1SingleSubscriberPublisher.html#_details) (I never used it myself to be honest) but, you can take a look at it.